# How can I hide/show advanced custom fields based on selection of a select field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created some advanced custom fields. One of them is a `select` field, where you can choose between sale and charter.

I want to hide/show some of my advanced custom fields based on what is currently selected (sale or charter).

How can I do this?

Comment: Show your effort here what you did so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ACf Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BnZA.png)

As shown in image (Click link) there is an option in the ACF to show fields conditionally based on other fields value whether it is Checkbox or Select box.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer covers the back end. For the front end template, something like this:

```
if (get_field('select_field_name') == 'sale'){
    //show some stuff i.e. the_field('field_name');
}
elseif (get_field('select_field_name') == 'charter') {
    //show other fields
}
else {
    //maybe do something here
}
```